# How to separate the files and folder names in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array of files and folders. This is the array

```
array("index.php","/examples","/myproject","scan.php","/wordpress","background.png","script.js");
```

I just want the array to be displayed as

```
FILES
index.php
scan.php
background.png
script.js


FOLDER
/examples
/myproject
/wordpress
```

My question is can I separate the files and folder?? I struck here can anyone help me out?? Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Yes you can separate them 2) How can you be stuck if you didn't even tried something and showed it here?

Comment: I just can echo all the file with `while` loop but cant seperate!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array("index.php","/examples","/myproject","scan.php","/wordpress","background.png","script.js");

$file = $dir = [];
foreach($array as $filename) {
    if (strpos($filename, '.') === false) {
        $dir[] = $filename;
    } else {
        $file[] = $filename;
    }
}
```

If You put this

```
var_dump($file);
var_dump($dir);
```

OUTPUT will be

```
array("index.php","scan.php","background.png","script.js")
array("/examples","/myproject","/wordpress")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array("index.php","/examples","/myproject","scan.php","/wordpress","background.png","script.js");

$files = [];
$dirs = [];
foreach($array as $filename) {
    if (strpos($filename, '.') === false) {
        $dirs[] = $filename;
    } else {
        $files[] = $filename;
    }
}

// Output: $files, $dirs
```

Comment: file may have no extension

Comment: @mylxsw I think i don't have problem with that!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = ["index.php","/examples","/myproject","scan.php","/wordpress","background.png","script.js"];
$files = $folders = [];
foreach ($arr AS $f) {
    if (strpos($f, '/') === 0) {
        $folders[] = $f;
    } else {
        $files[] = $f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array("index.php","/examples","/myproject","scan.php","/wordpress","background.png","script.js");

$files = []; 
$folders = [];
foreach($array as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, '/') === false) {
        $files[] = $value;
    } 
    else {
        $folders[] = $value;
    }
}
```